# Luminace, RGB, and SMPT ST 2084 EOTF

Tags: colorspace

I need a point clarified.  According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_video), SMPT ST 2084 EOTF is this:  [image]

I've seen this equation implemented in game engines where for **L** they feed the channels **RGB**, each of which is 0 to 10,000 and normalize them.  Am confused because luminance from what I understand is supposed to be one quantity instead of 3.  I understood luminance to be kind'a like speed in physics, and the RGB is the "direction" vector. Is it really correct to plug the RGB linear channels in into **L** (the "linear optical luminance") in this equation, or am I misunderstanding something? The way I think of it, we need to compute the luminance from the RGB triplet, and then plug that value into L, then from V we compute colors.

Where is my thinking wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully understand the confusion (I was also a bit confused when I saw it). So, I decided to look at the ACES implementation of the ST 2084 EOTF. https://github.com/ampas/aces-dev/blob/v1.0.3/transforms/ctl/lib/ACESlib.Utilities_Color.ctl#L402

From there it is very clear: You perform the transfer function on the R, G and B values separately and not by first calculating the luminance. The confusion most likely comes from the fact that we are talking about two different kinds of luminance.

We have [*relative luminance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance), which is the luminance we use when talking about colours and can be calculated with $Y=0.2126R+0.7152G+0.0722B$

We also have [*luminance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance) for which the SI unit is cd/m2 and basically means how bright something is.

You, and I when I first read your post, were thinking about *relative luminance*, but the Wikipedia article was talking about just *luminance*. In this case, it talks about the luminance of red light, green light and blue light separately (since a camera captures it separately and a monitor produces it separately). I'm pretty sure the ST 2048 spec is more clear about this, but that's behind a paywall.

Comment: I think spectral radiance (from Radiometry) might be the better term to refer to the values used in the EOTF for L. Luminance (or relative luminance if it's normalized 1 or 100) from photometry is the one that I was incorrectly thinking of. Correct me if I'm wrong just so that I don't throw someone off out there :) thanks.